# Transform Aspx to Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, queue, transform

I get the link in "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIs7ZsMCUWA&t=327s"

I want to change from aspx to winform

the problem:

in aspx

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (Session["TokenQueue"] == null)
            {
                Queue<int> queueTokens = new Queue<int>();
                Session["TokenQueue"] = queueTokens;
            }

    }

    protected void btnPrinToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Queue<int> tokenQueue = (Queue<int>)Session["TokenQueue"];
        lblStatus.Text = " Terdapat " + tokenQueue.Count.ToString() + " Antrian ";

        if (Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] == null)
        {
            Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] = 0;
        }

        int nextTokenNumberTobeIssued = (int)Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] + 1;
        Session["LastTokenNumberIssued"] = nextTokenNumberTobeIssued;
        tokenQueue.Enqueue(nextTokenNumberTobeIssued);

        AddTokensToListBox(tokenQueue);
    }
```

in c# can't read session?

Session["TokenQueue"] = queueTokens;

how to use session in c# winform?

Comment: Session is something specific to aps.net and web app in particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session normally helps us to maintain information for a user across multiple pages in a web application. When you are converting any web application to windows application you need to know the certain aspects of web application. As session is pretty common in most of web application frameworks. You can achieve same behavior by static variables in any language. In C# you can make a class to hold such information in static variables like this

```
internal static class SESSIONWINFORM
    {
        public static string TokenQueue = string.Empty;
        public static DateTime LastLogin = DateTime.MinValue;
        // more variables as you needed

    }
```

Then you assign these variables values at particular events of your windows application for example in login method to save logged in time like this

```
       protected bool login(string username, string password) {

            if (succesfullLogic)
            {
                SESSIONWINFORM.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;   
                ....
            }
        }
```

And to show in a Label1 to user his last login in a WinForm. You can set it text like this

```
  Label1.Text = SESSIONWINFORM.LastLogin;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sessions since Windows apps run within the user context. There is always a single user.

I would advice to make the variable a static variable, since then it really is shared for the lifetime of the session, as it would in ASP.NET. What if you make  a `Session` class in your Winforms project and mimic the session behavior? That would make it easier to exchange code between your projects.